# Simple keyboard macro to jump to \begin{document} regardless of current location in file

Tags: keyboard-macros

If you are in the preamble of a TeX document you can do `C-s \begin{document}` or `C-r \begin{document}` if you are in the body of the document. It would useful to have a simple, all-purpose macro (say, `M-D`) that would accomplish this no matter where you are in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s easy. First start by recording a macro. You do this by calling `kmacro-start-macro-or-insert-counter`, which by default is bound to `F3`. Then perform the actions you want your macro to do. In this case, I recommend running `C-<home>` followed by `C-s \begin{document}`. Then end your recording by calling `kmacro-end-or-call-macro`, which is bound to `F4`.

Now you want to give that macro a name, so type `C-x C-k n` (`kmacro-name-last-macro`). You can also bind it to a key with `C-x C-k b` (`kmacro-bind-to-key`) if you want to go ahead and start using it (you can also call it by hitting `F4` again).

Finally, open your init file and type `M-x insert-kbd-macro`. Enter the same name that you gave the macro. This will insert code to define the macro at startup. All you have to add is a key binding, which you can do in the usual way.

Don’t forget to save your init file.

Comment: OK, but doesn't that simply enact `C-s`? Which would be fine if the current location in the document is *before* `\begin{document`, but will fail if current location is *after* `\begin{document`. I imagine that what I am looking for is something that would require some (e)lisp magic, which, unfortunately is beyond me.

Comment: `M-< C-s \begin{document}`

Comment: Ah, and apologies. I read the answer from @db48x too quickly. Accept the answer.